# how to exit the center the Scene view on a GameObject view mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

"

Center the view on a GameObject
To center the Scene view on a GameObject, select the GameObject in the Hierarchy, then move the mouse over the Scene view and press F. If the GameObject is already selected, F zooms in to the pivot point. This feature can also be found in the menu bar under Edit > Frame Selected.

To lock the view to the GameObject even when the GameObject is moving, press Shift+F. This feature is also in the menu bar under Edit > Lock View to Selected.

Unity doc

"

so after pressing f what should I do to exit that view mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F to zoom isn't a mode so there's no mode to exit. Shift+f to lock the frame locks it until a key is pressed that would pan the camera. I can't remember if mouse look will break the lock but I know adjusting position does.

If you think your camera is stuck and you can't pan or mouse look then you might be in Game View; there should be another tab at the top of the viewport window to go to Scene View that lets you move around.

Comment: My camera cannot stop focus that object, I want to move the camera freely like the first time I use

Comment: @Newbie Are you on scene view or game view? If you go to the camera in the project hierarchy and change its transform values does that change the camera view?

Comment: after I move the object, restart unity, and move the camera, my camera works fine again, thank you